# google data studio embedded reports URL params not working

Tags: looker-studio

Passing URL parameters into a Google Data Studio (GDS) Embedded report is no longer working.

I used to be able to pass [JSON ENCODED](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters) URL parameters into an Embedded report using the following method:

```
https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/REPORT_ID/page/PAGE_ID?config=JSON_ENCODED_URL_PARAMETERS
```

This is no longer working. However URL Parameters are working when you preview the GDS report this way:

```
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/REPORT_ID/page/PAGE_ID?params=JSON_ENCODED_URL_PARAMETERS
```

I cannot find a solution to pass the url parameters into my report? I need to pass a variable in order to filter the report data.